# Massive content replace on php data

Tags: php

I would like to perform massive content replace for some data called from mysql db in a php file.

Firstly, I have prepared an replacement array for content replace:-

```
$replacement_array = array(
    "###123###" => "hello",
    "###456###" => "great",
    "###789###" => "ok"
);
```

Secondly, I call data from mysql db, the data would look like this:-

```
$data = "<input type="text" name="field1" value="###123###"><input type="text" name="field2" value="###789###">";
```

Thirdly, refer to the array, check up if `$data` contains any matched value in `$replacement_array` (this is the black box I wish to consult).

Fourthly, after content replacement, the resulting `$data` would become this:-

```
$data = "<input type="text" name="field1" value="hello"><input type="text" name="field2" value="ok">";
```

I guess the above will involve php `in_array()`,  `str_replace()` and `preg_match()`, and I guess the flow may be like this:-

1) use `explode()` function to chop `$data` into a new `$data_array` by ###;

2) check values in `$data_array` is `in_array()` of `$replacement_array`;

3) if `in_array()`, carry out `str_replace();` (in the above example there will be 2 times)

4) `$data` has proceeded 2 times of content replace, and ready to be used.

if the above steps 3) and 4) are carried out step by step, I it will be easy, however, if I wish to do it in 1 time, how shall I handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with first parameter as search array and second parameter as replace array.

```
$arr = array("###123###","###456###","###789###");
$arr1 = array("hello","great","ok");
str_replace($arr,$arr1, $data);
```

Comment: Or use `strtr` function directly with the original array,just `strtr($data,$replacement_array)`